# How can I find what the lowest number is that a number is divisible by(other than 1)?

Tags: php, math

How can I find what the lowest number is that a number is divisible by(other than 1)?

So for example, I have the number 33. I know that the lowest number it is divisible by is 3, but I would like to know how to figure that out with PHP.

Comment: What is the biggest number you will be working with?  This problem is equivalent to finding the "smallest prime factor" of a number.

Comment: Peter O.s' comment means there are (infinitely many) large numbers for which finding such divisors will take _very long_ time.

Answer (score 6):

Use simple for loop, with '%' operator:

```
<?php
$number = 33;
for($i=2; $i <= $number; ++$i)
{
    if($number % $i == 0)
    {
        echo 'lowest number is '.$i;
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: It's only necessary to test up to the square root of number. e.g $i * $i <= $number

Comment: @samgak how about prime numbers where the lowest divisor would be itself. I guess you could determine if it's prime before looping to minimise repetitions

Comment: @scrowler If the loop completes without finding a divisor then you can assume that's what you have

Comment: Yeah good point. Edge case to be handled is 1, because te OP doesn't want 1 returned

Answer (score 3):

You can use a method like this:

```
/**
 * Return the lowest whole divisor for the passed in number, greater than one
 * @param  int       $number
 * @return int|false The lowest divisor (above one). Last resort is that the return
 *                   value will be the number passed in, or bool false if you passed
 *                   in 1
 */
function lowestWholeDivisor($number)
{
    for ($i = 2; $i <= $number; $i++) {
        $calc = $number / $i;
        // is_int() will return false if the input is a float, e.g. has a decimal point
        if (is_int($calc)) {
            return $i;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var_dump(lowestWholeDivisor(33)); // 3
var_dump(lowestWholeDivisor(1));  // false
var_dump(lowestWholeDivisor(2));  // 2
var_dump(lowestWholeDivisor(3));  // 3
var_dump(lowestWholeDivisor(4));  // 2
var_dump(lowestWholeDivisor(5));  // 5
var_dump(lowestWholeDivisor(6));  // 2
```